# Spring Websockets in Glassfish - Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received

Tags: spring-boot, glassfish, spring-websocket, stomp, payara

I am currently trying to implement Spring Websockets in Glassfish. I've done this so far, but when I try to connect, the server doesn't return a Sec-WebSocket protocol. In Google Chrome I get the following error:

```
Error during WebSocket handshake: Sent non-empty 'Sec-WebSocket-Protocol' header but no response was received.
```

Request and Response as Image shown in Google Chrome:

[image]

As a Stomp Client, I am using ng2-stompjs in Angular.

I tried on Tomcat 9.0.17 and WildFly 16 and everything is working as expected.

WebSocket Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
@EnableWebSocket
public class WebSocketConfiguration implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOrigins("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/topic");
    }
}
```

glassfish-web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE glassfish-web-app PUBLIC "-//GlassFish.org//DTD GlassFish Application Server 3.1 Servlet 3.0//EN" "http://glassfish.org/dtds/glassfish-web-app_3_0-1.dtd">
<glassfish-web-app>
    <context-root>/monitoring</context-root>
    <classloading-delegate>false</classloading-delegate>
    <parameter-encoding default-charset="UTF-8"/>
</glassfish-web-app>
```

build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.4.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    id 'war'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'de.conting'
version = '0.0.1'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
configurations {
    compile.exclude module: 'spring-boot-starter-tomcat'
    compile.exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat'
}

war {
    enabled = true
}
dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jersey'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-quartz'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-websocket'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.2.Final'
    implementation 'io.jsonwebtoken:jjwt:0.9.1'
    runtimeOnly 'org.postgresql:postgresql'
    providedCompile group: 'javax.servlet', name: 'javax.servlet-api', version: '4.0.1'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.6'
}
```

Comment: in the end did you manage to solve it? I'm experiencing the same problem :(